# Analysis or (abstract) algebra first?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, self-learning, advice, learning

Which one would you recommend? I only know calculus and linear algebra when it comes to university-level mathematics. Is one required to understand the other?

Comment: I'm not confident with my answer, but I personally liked learning Analysis before Algebra. It taught me how to understand abstract ideas with an intuitive introduction, whereas abstract algebra can get a bit *abstract*.

Comment: I would say start with analysis if you haven't had any real work in proofs.

Comment: I seriously thought this a math-history question when I read the title of the question. Now for my serious answer. I think before tackling either, you should go back and relearn your calculus and linear algebra to make the transition to both subject as smooth as possible. It's more important to have a firmer foundation than trying to learn something more advance than you can handle.

Comment: @Nameless: You're saying I should relearn my linear algebra and calculus, but how do I know when I've got a good enough understanding of them, especially considering I've passed courses in them?

Comment: required by whom and what for?

Comment: I would recommend asking someone in the Math Department at your institution. They are the ones who know their courses best, both the ones you have done and the ones you want to do, and they also know you.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this were really an "exclusive or". I'd tend to think that doing both at once is far better than just doing one at a time.